# IDE doesn't recognize conftest.py as a python file

Tags: pycharm, pytest, conftest

I have a python project with tests and a conftest file, and a few days ago - out of nowhere - Pycharm decided that it's not a python script:

[image]

The result is that I can't debug it, can't jump to source, don't have inspection and ext'.

Moreover - If I change the name to something different, all of the sudden it's a python script again:

[image]

Why is this happening? Can anyone tell? I searched the settings for mentions of `conftest` and found nothing. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is probably a bug - I have seen this once, but I don't remember what I did to fix it. For sure it was no radical measure (like clearing the settings), but just something like remove / readd, or rename to something with another extension and back. You may also try `File/Invalidate Caches`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`conftest.py` has a wrong file type assigned to it, check **Settings | Editor | File Types | Text** and remove `conftest.py` from "File Name Patterns".

[image]